# Unable to do a fresh install of Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I had VSforMac installed but it kept giving errors when I tried to update.

[image]

So I uninstalled by dragging the application from the Applications folder to trash. Then, I followed all the steps given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/uninstalling-xamarin#uninstallmac) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1149129/how-to-completely-remove-visual-studio-from-mac).

I also cleared the Xamarin install cache and everything Xamarin (shown below from using DaisyDisk)

[image]

[image]

Now when I install Xamarin (using current latest VisualStudioForMacInstaller__798720203.1520912446.dmg) which I think should be a fresh install, I keep getting the following errors:

```
    Visual Studio installation failed with more than one exception (Attempt #3)
Message: Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: System.AggregateException

at Xamarin.Web.Installer.MacInstallationArchiveHandler.MountDmg (System.String path) [0x0005c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/4c42ab4a/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MacInstallationArchiveHandler.Mac.cs:71
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.MacInstallationArchiveHandler.InstallDmg (System.String path, System.Boolean needsPrivileges) [0x00035] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/4c42ab4a/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MacInstallationArchiveHandler.Mac.cs:100
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install (System.String path, System.Boolean needsPrivileges) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/4c42ab4a/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/InstallationArchiveHandler.cs:31
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.MacInstallationArchiveHandler.MountDmg (System.String path) [0x0005c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/4c42ab4a/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MacInstallationArchiveHandler.Mac.cs:
```

What is the problem?

Comment: sounds like there is a corrupt DMG